# What I make wrong and Cannot inset a value at sqlite3 using custom trigger?

Tags: trigger, sqlite3

I am making the follwing table at SQLITE3:

```
CREATE table IF NOT EXISTS redirect (
            id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
            url_from TEXT not null,
            url_to TEXT not null,
            method TEXT not null,
            http_status_code INTEGER not null CHECK( http_status_code IN (300,301,302,304,304,308,307) ) DEFAULT 301,
            use_in_https INTEGER not null CHECK(use_in_https IN (0,1)) DEFAULT 0,
            use_in_http INTEGER not null CHECK(use_in_http IN (0,1)) DEFAULT 1,
            exact_match INTEGER not null CHECK(exact_match IN (0,1)) DEFAULT 1
        );

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS remove_http_https;

        CREATE TRIGGER remove_http_https BEFORE INSERT ON redirect BEGIN 
           SELECT CASE WHEN NEW.url_from THEN REPLACE(REPLACE(NEW.url_from,"http:\/\/",""),"https:\/\/","")   END;
        END;
```

And in order to test the trigger I do the following:

```
INSERT INTO redirect (url_from,url_to, method) VALUES ("https:\/\/google.com","https:\/\/example.com","GET");
```

But I get the error:

```
Parse error near line 17: no such column: https:\/\/google.com
  T INTO redirect (url_from,url_to, method) VALUES ("https:\/\/google.com","http
                                      error here ---^
Parse error near line 23: no such column: https:\/\/google.com
  T INTO redirect (url_from,url_to, method) VALUES ("https
```

Any ideas about the syntax error? What did I mess up?

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas about the syntax error? What did I mess up?

1.Wrong [quotes](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html) used

```
'keyword'       A keyword in single quotes is a string literal.
"keyword"       A keyword in double-quotes is an identifier.
[keyword]       A keyword enclosed in square brackets is an identifier. 
`keyword`       A keyword enclosed in grave accents (ASCII code 96) is an identifier.
```

2.The trigger.

> I need to remove both http and https.

[From the docs](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html)

> The value of NEW.rowid is undefined in a BEFORE INSERT trigger in
> which the rowid is not explicitly set to an integer.
>
> Because of the behaviors described above, programmers are encouraged
> to prefer AFTER triggers over BEFORE triggers.

You can use an AFTER INSERT trigger as follows

```
CREATE TRIGGER remove_http_https 
   AFTER INSERT ON redirect
    FOR EACH ROW 
      BEGIN
       UPDATE redirect 
          SET url_from = REPLACE(REPLACE(NEW.url_from,'http://',''),'https://','') 
       WHERE id=NEW.id;
END;
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/cA0WAqAD)

Comment: I need to remove both `http` and `https`.

Comment: @DimitriosDesyllas edited , added an explanation on the trigger used

Answer (score 0):

Expanding Ergest Basha's answer to add:

3. `/` characters doesn't have to be escaped with `\`
4. Your trigger is doing nothing. A select doesn't change anything in the row being inserted and REPLACE() is a string function with no effect on the parameters you pass it, unless you assign the result to something.

To correct the url you have to use an AFTER trigger to update the row you just inserted:

```
CREATE TRIGGER remove_http_https 
   AFTER INSERT ON redirect
   WHEN (instr(NEW.url_from,'http://') OR instr(NEW.url_from,'https://'))
BEGIN
   UPDATE redirect 
   SET url_from = REPLACE(REPLACE(NEW.url_from,'http://',''),'https://','') 
   WHERE rowid=NEW.rowid;
END;
```

Here is the [updated Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Mx2yqo6b)

The same trigger can also update `url_to`, if you need it, but to handle any UPDATE on the table you need a separate AFTER UPDATE trigger with the same code.

Comment: Wouldn't the update statement inside the trigger, also trigger the AFTER UPDATE one as well?

Comment: @DimitriosDesyllas Yes. You can avoid unnecessary firing of the triggers by adding a WHEN clause to both AFTER INSERT and AFTER UPDATE triggers. I edited the answer adding the WHEN clause.